# Costumize HTML render of Django form with MultipleChoiceField and the widget CheckboxSelectMultiple

Tags: python, django, checkbox, django-forms

Im creating a Django form that allows to select multiple options (checkbox) and stores a list of characters in the database. The backend works as expected but the frontend renders not nicely.
Actually, there are no checkboxes appearing in html.

Here what I did in models.py

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
field = models.CharField(max_length=70, default='good')
```

In forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import MyModel

CHOICES = (
    ('good', 'good'),
    ('c1', 'c1'),
    ('c2', 'c2'),
    ('c3', 'c3'),
    ('c4', 'c4'),
)

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=CHOICES,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['field', ]
```

In views.py

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import MyForm

def new_odontogram(request):
    my_form = MyForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            my_form.save()
            messages.success(request,'Data stored !')
            return redirect('index')
    return render(request, 'my_form_page.html', {'my_form': my_form})
```

The html code belows acts well for the backend, in my_form_page.html:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ my_form.as_p }}
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">
       <button type="submit">Record</button>
    </a>
</form>
```

However, as I mentioned at the beginning, there are no boxes displayed and I wish to costumize them. So, I read somewhere that there there is some way to loop over the options and add a  option that helps to display these boxes.

So I tried this:

```
{% for option in my_form.field %}
    <label for="{{ option.id_for_label }}">
        <input type="checkbox" value="{{ option.choice_label }}" id="{{ option.id_for_label }}">
        <span class="checkable">{{ option.choice_label }}</span>
    </label>
{% endfor %}
```

With that I can see the boxes displayed, but the backend is broken. I'd appreciate a lot your help to set up correctly this html loop, I guess the **name** argument is missing but I have no idea of what to include in.

This was run on Django 3.0.5 and Python 3.6.9, I'm using PicnicCSS for styling

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: `name="field"` we name it from `forms.py`. This is what will be in name attribute but still I'm not sure it will work or not.

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback, you comment shed light to solve this problem. Finally I overcome the issue by setting the name argument as   **name="{{ field.data.name }}"**   This is a generic version that will work for other forms.